# Reading line from file which holds braces and comma

Tags: file, ksh

in ksh I have a input file that holds the following:

```
$ cat input.txt
A {111 222 111}
B {333,444,333}
C {555 666 555}
$
```

When I Run the following command Im getting the following

```
$ while read LINE
> do 
>   echo $LINE
> done<input.txt
A {111 222 111}
B 333 444 333
C {555 666 555}
$


How to insure to read lines as is with braces and comma?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid special syntax with braces and coma in ksh when you are doing an echo, add quotation marks around `$LINE`:

```bash
while read LINE
do 
    echo "$LINE"
done<input.txt
```

The syntax `{1,2,3...}` is useful for loops:

```bash
for x in {1,a,3}; do echo x=$x; done
x=1
x=a
x=3
```

Comment: `while IFS= read -r LINE` is the idiomatic way to read a line with exactly as it appears in the input.